# Get last character in string using JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the last character in this string below using JS RegExp:

```
function getLastChar(i){
    return ???;
}

getLastChar("Hello Word!");
```

How can I get only the "!" in return using RegExp.

Comment: `i[i.length-1]` and don't be over complicated unnecessarily

Comment: why regex? `return i[i.length - 1];`

Comment: if you really want a regex: `(.)$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
// RegExp way
function getLastChar1(str){
 var r = (/.$/).exec(str);
 if(r){
  return r[0]
 }
 return str;
}

// last string way
function getLastChar2(str){
 if(str.length){
  return str[str.length-1]
 }
 return str;
}


console.log(getLastChar1("Hello Word!"))
console.log(getLastChar2("Hello Word!"))
```